# Rewriting URL rule, example like StackOverflow

Tags: php, apache

What would be the apache rewrite url to extract the id number (434376) from this url?

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434376/unique-url-slug
```

something like

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteRule ^questions/([0-9]+)/?$([A-Za-z0-9-]+)   post.php?post_id=$1 [NC,L]
```

...but it doesnt work on my site...any tips?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested:

```
RewriteRule ^questions/([0-9]+)/?.*$   rewrite.php?post_id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if the / is optional it probably should be:

```
RewriteRule ^questions/([0-9]+)/?([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?/?$   post.php?post_id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Let me know if it works..